# Find all in prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

I have some employees:

```
employee(2,2,'George','Johnson','12/16/1987').
employee(4,3,'Noah','Jones','6/9/1984').
employee(5,4,'Jack','Brown','2/16/1992').
employee(6,6,'Charlie','Davis','3/28/1997').
employee(7,1,'Leo','Miller','6/6/1997').
employee(8,6,'Jacob','Wilson','2/16/1997').
```

I want to print of all them. I do it so now:

```
run :- findall(Id, employee(Id, _, _, _, _), L), writeEmployees(L).

writeEmployees([]) :- !.
writeEmployees([Id|T]) :- employee(Id, PosId, FN, LN, Birth), 
   writeq(employee(Id, PosId, FN, LN, Birth)), nl, writeEmployees(T).
```

And it works, but it doesn't look ok, I mean, there're too many '_'s and I have to write 'Id, PosId, FN, LN, Birth' string. How can find employee directly in findall()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing really terribly wrong with what you have. Yes, you have four `_` but that's fine if you do not care about any of those 4 arguments.

However, you are skipping those arguments, then just retrieving them again later. If you want to avoid that, you could write your `findall` to capture everything you want, then write that list out with `maplist`.

```
run :-
    findall(employee(Id, PosId, FN, LN, Birth),
            employee(Id, PosId, FN, LN, Birth), Employees),
    writeEmployees(Employees).

writeEmployee(E) :- writeq(E), nl.
writeEmployees(Es) :- maplist(writeEmployee, Es).
```

Ultimately, though, it depends upon the broader application this might fit into. If you are managing employees in a broader case, it really is more efficient to manage them by `Id` and then retrieve the details only when you need them, as you currently have. You could, though, rewrite your current `writeEmployees` with `maplist`:

```
writeEmployee(Id) :-
    employee(Id, PosId, FN, LN, Birth), 
    writeq(employee(Id, PosId, FN, LN, Birth)), nl.

writeEmployees(EmployeeIds) :-
    maplist(writeEmployee, EmployeeIds).
```